# Newton's method for a vector field

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be $C^2$ and let $f(x^*)=0$. Since

$$f(x^*) \approx f(x) + Df(x) (x^* - x)$$

we can have the iterative procedure

$$x_{k+1} = x_k - Df(x_k)^{-1} f(x_k)$$

Is $G(x): = x - Df(x)^{-1} f(x)$ invertible near $x=x_0$? Are there any results on the convergence of this procedure?

---

I tried to use the inverse function theorem. However, I do not know how to prove that $$DG(x_0) = I - D(Df(x)^{-1} f(x)) \bigg |_{x_0}$$ is non-singular.

Comment: Do you have an expression for its determinant?

Comment: Perhaps the method needs to be contractive?
I think Lyapunov stability https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability means it does not blow up. Or perhaps it was the energy method one used. I think Taylor expansions can be used to find bounds of the error ?

Comment: I was likely thinking about the fixed point theorem when talking about the mapping being contractive: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem. I have some faint memory about negative eigenvalues being good as well, but can't remember the exact motivation, probably something about matrix powers.

Comment: Asking for $G$ to be invertible is a strange question: ideally $G(x)=x_0$ and $G$ is *not* invertible! This will happen when $f$ is linear. The general situation seems quite complex and I'm not sure I expect $G$ invertible for "typical" $f$.

Comment: We know that if $B:= I + A$ and $||A|| < \epsilon$, then $det(B) \not = 0$. I tried to use this fact. However, it is not clear to me why the norm of jacobian of  $Df(x)^{-1} f(x)$ at $x_0$ is small?

Comment: @Emil: Thanks for your comment. It is interesting that this might be related to the stability of that equilibrium point. If we assume that $x_0$ is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point, then the Jacobian $Df(x_0)$ is non-singular (all eigenvalues have negative real part). I do not know what the Jecobian of $Df(x)^{-1}f(x)$ is.

Comment: Yes, we are looking for the fixed points of $G$. But my question now is about the invertibility of $G$ near $x_0$ and I think the best way to prove it is to use the inverse function theorem. As I said, we can assume that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: @user7530: Thanks. What do you mean by typical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This even doesn't hold for 1-D function since $$DG(x_0)=1-\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\right)'|_{x_0}=1-\dfrac{f'^2(x_0)-f(x_0)f''(x_0)}{f'^2(x_0)}=0$$which is singular. To show that for higher dimensions let's define $$Df^{-1}(x)=[a_{ij}(x)]\\Df^{-1}(x)f(x)=[c_{i}(x)]$$and $$D(Df^{-1}(x)f(x))=[b_{ij}(x)]$$therefore $$c_{i}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}(x)f_{k}(x)$$where $$f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}f_1(x)\\f_2(x)\\.\\.\\.\\f_n(x)\end{bmatrix}$$also$$b_{ij}(x)=\dfrac{\partial c_i}{\partial x_j}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial a_{ik}(x)}{\partial x_j}f_{k}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}(x)\dfrac{\partial f_k(x)}{\partial x_j}$$when substituting $x=x_0$, $f_k(x_0)$ becomes zero since $f(x_0)=0$ therefore$$b_{ij}(x_0)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}(x_0)\dfrac{\partial f_k(x)}{\partial x_j}|_{x_0}$$but $\dfrac{\partial f_k(x)}{\partial x_j}|_{x_0}$ is the (k,j)th entry of $Df(x_0)$ which by substitution leads to $$D(Df^{-1}(x)f(x))|_{x_0}=Df^{-1}(x_0)Df(x_0)=I$$or $$\Large DG(x_0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

The process

$$
x_k = x_{k-1}-Df^{-1}(x_{k-1})f(x_{k-1})
$$

can be written as

$$
x_k = \phi(x_{k-1})\\
x_{k-1} = \phi(x_{k-2})
$$

and then

$$
|x_k-x_{k-1}| = |\phi(x_{k-1})-\phi(x_{k-2})|  = |\phi'(\xi)||x_{k-1}-x_{k-2}|
$$

for a suitable $\xi\in (x_{k-1}-x_{k-2})$ hence is sufficient that $|\phi'(\xi)| < 1$ for convergence

Comment: Thank you for the comment on the convergence. I guess $f(x_k)$ is a typo. It should be $f(x_{k-1})$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes. It was a typo already corrected. Thanks.